# Is $P$ a zero divisor modulo $(Q)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $P,Q\in \mathbb{C}[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]$ such that $V(P,Q)=\emptyset$ (they have no zeros in common). Is it possible to assure that $P+(Q)$ is not a zero divisor of the ring $R:=\mathbb{C}[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]/(Q)$? I also suppose that $V(Q)\neq \emptyset$, which by the Krull's Hauptidealsatz, implies that the Krull dimension of $V(Q)$ is $n-1$ (taking as proven that $\dim_{Krull}(\mathbb{A}^{n}(\mathbb{C}))=n$, where $\mathbb{A}^{n}(\mathbb{C})$ denotes the complex affine space).

Ok, so, first, if $P+(Q)$ is a zero divisor of $R$, we would have that there exists $\tilde{P}\not\in (Q)$ such that $P\cdot \tilde{P}\in (Q)$. This must be in contradiction somehow with the fact that $V(P,Q)=\emptyset$ (which by the Nullstellensatz, implies that $(P,Q)=(1)$), but I am a little stucked... Any hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The answer is that if $R\neq 0$, $P$ cannot be a zero divisor. ($R=0$ is equivalent to $Q$ a nonzero constant.)

From your assumption that $V(Q)\neq\emptyset$, we have that $R\neq 0$. By the nullstellensatz, $V(P,Q)=\emptyset$ implies $(P,Q)=1$. This gives that $(\overline{P})\subset R$ is the unit ideal, where $\overline{P}$ denotes the image of $P$ in $R$. In particular, $\overline{P}$ is a unit: there is some $S\in R$ so that $S\overline{P}=1$. Now $\overline{P}$ can't be a zerodivisor - if $T\in R$ is a nonzero element such that $T\overline{P}=0$, we would have $0=ST\overline{P}=T$, contrary to our assumption that $T\neq 0$.

Comment: You have solved my doubts perfectly, already written it down carefully, with full understanding of the matter. Thanks! +1